# Intellij's Inspection on interface declaring incompatible 'Object' method

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am in the process of setting up an Inspection Profile to match Errors/Warnings Preferences of Eclipse. One of the rule in Eclipse is

"Interface method conflicts with protected 'Object' method"

whereby an interface declared as

```
interface I {
   int clone();
}
```

is flagged as a warning. Which is rightly done because no class can implement this as it is incompatible with the signature of `Object`'s `clone` method.

How can I have a similar warning shown in IntelliJ. I have failed to find an inspection rule in IntelliJ corresponding to the Eclipse's one.

Comment: As an alternative approach, I can make use of Structural Search Inspection where I can set up an expression that matches such interface. It seem to work, but still waiting for better (and perhaps) standard solution

Answer (score 2):

Since IntelliJ IDEA 16 the *Interface method clashes with method in 'java.lang.Object'* inspection is available to warn about this issue.